# How can I change one page to another without using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to implement quiz module in my application which consists 14 questions so  how do i go from one question to another. If i use intent then this is not smart work because i have need to create 14 activities. is there any other ways to move to next page without using intent.?

Comment: you can use fragments and replace one fragment with another

Comment: okay.But in fragment how can i implement the designing?

Comment: google for tutorials on fragments you will find so much articles,you can inflate any layout in fragments

Comment: If u have code then pls upload it.

Comment: i don't know what you want to design so my code won't help you

Comment: Check : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

Comment: Actully i have 14 to 15 questions and each question maintain single page so when i click next question that directly move to next page and there would be same designing example textview and radio group.

Comment: Okay i frnds thank u so much to all i will try to implement fragment if i will face difficulties than i will again contact to u.thank u dear yadav.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fragment inside your activity which load your view with data. For this you need to ID to get the data for example Question 1 have ID 1 which will be fetching from database and display in your view, this will be implementing in your fragment, firstly get the ID and query in your database for fetch that record and then display in your view and this fragment object will initiate and set in your layout. Now after question complete pass the next question ID to your fragment with new initialization and replace with current fragment.

Answer (score 0):

***You can achieve this in two ways***

### 1) Using Fragments:

- Have 15 fragments
- All are mounted on a single container
- Start one fragment to another dynamically

### 2) Using a Single activity

- Have 1 Textview for question
- Say if you have objectives answers have radio buttons for them
- Then u have to write a logic to dynamically change the data one after
  another keeping the same activity

---

### Best Approach

***Using the Fragments Would be best and simple way to achieve your objective  because second option unnecessarily complicates the things***

---

### Online Sources to learn fragments

- [*If you have not used fragments before click here to check developer
  docs*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
- [*Simple tutorial to learn fragments*](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score -1):

I assume your modules are in different layouts. Then you can use above syntax to change to another one:

```
setContentView(R.layout.second);
```